# Pass all other query params in apache htaccess rewrite / redirect?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to match certain query params, and redirect to some new url but not lose all other query params (e.g. utm, etc)

For instance if the request is

```
home.com/request?a=1&utm=stuff
```

I want to redirect to

```
home/com/target?utm=stuff
```

not

```
home/com/target?&utm=stuff
```

I know $1 $2 etc refer to groups of the rewrite rule,
and %1 %2 refer to groups of the query string.

The following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^request$
Rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.)a=1(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /?%1%2 [L,R=302]
```

subtracts the `a=1`, but does not handle the & smartly.

Comment: I'm trying to match a specific request, not just query params, but query params on a specific uri, not other uris.

I don't think the additional uri condition would make much of a difference as far as the answer to this problem though, do you?

Comment: But additional uri condition will definitely stop rule to execute if `asfd` isn't part of original URL i.e. `home.com/request?utm=stuff&a=1&other=stuff`

Comment: good catch. i made it uniform. i switched while constructing the example. The question is basically how do I trim the first `&` for the target url's query params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?a=1(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^request/?$ /target?%1%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: genius. thanks. I didn't know about non-capturing groups, and nesting.

Comment: It gets a little bit tricky if desired query parameter can appear in any order in query string.

Comment: For that, I shimmed in an ampersand in my code that generates the code if the request query param has query params. This is good enough for my situation